# Right triangle problem involving circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, angle

What is the length of line X and line Y such that, together with line B, they form a right triangle?

Note:
-the vertex between line X and line Y should be a point in the circle
-the angle between line X and line Y is 90 degrees

A rephrasing of the problem would be:
"Given the right triangle XYB tangent to the circle at vertex B, and line A intersecting the circle's center and bisecting side B, what is the length of the sides X and Y such that side B is perpendicular to line A?"

[image]

Comment: You must find the intersections between the large circle and the circle of diameter $B$.

Comment: without knowledge of the horizontal position of  $B$, this can not be solved.

Comment: @robjohn line A is a line connecting the center and topmost point of the circle. side B is perpendicular to line A. line A bisects side B. the distance between the intersection of line A & side B and the center of the circle is 23.849093. the length of side B is 5.374295.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Given $|OT|=|OB|=r=26$,
$XY\perp OT$, $|XY|=b=5.374295$
$|MX|=|MY|=\tfrac12b$, $|OM|=d=23.849093$,
$\angle XBY=90^\circ$.

Find $|BX|,|BY|$.

Let $O=(0,0)$, $T=(0,r)$.
Then
\begin{align}
X=( \tfrac12b,d)=(&2.6871475,23.849093)
,\\
Y=(-\tfrac12b,d)=(-&2.6871475,23.849093)
,
\end{align}

Note that since $\angle XBY=90^\circ$,
$M$ is the center of circumscribed circle around $\triangle XBC$,
we have

\begin{align}
|MB|&=|MX|=|MY|=\tfrac12b,
\\
\cos\phi&=\frac{r^2+d^2-(\tfrac12b)^2}{2\,r\,d}
=0.997908031422582
,\\
B&=(r\,\sqrt{1-\cos^2\phi},\ r\,\cos\phi)
=(1.68088759763376,25.9456088169871)
,\\
|BX|&=\sqrt{(B_x-X_x)^2+(B_y-X_y)^2}
=2.32549727198021
,\\
|BY|&=\sqrt{(B_x-Y_x)^2+(B_y-Y_y)^2}
=4.8451118857089
.
\end{align}